# Disable a Spring Scheduler Task via Property

Tags: java, spring, cron, task, scheduler

I am scheduling a task using Spring Framework and have a cron value set through an environment specific property file. I am looking for a way to disable this task through a property so that only certain environments run this task.

```xml
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="theClass" method="theMethod" cron="${scheduler.cron}" /> 
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="theClass" class="com.test.TheClass" scope="prototype" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Spring environment profiles [(example using annotations](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), [example using xml](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)), so you can have different profiles for development, testing, production, etc. And these are set via properties (spring.profiles.active).

Comment: We are currently using Spring [ConfigurableEnvironment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html) with [MutablePropertySources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html) in order to handle environment specific values. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to annotate my class?  Ideally I would like to configure this strictly in the spring configuration and outside of the Java code to maintain current conventions.

Comment: You can use XML to configure the profiles. See the second link I've just added.