# How to override/turnoff scheduled tasks in test of Spring context

Tags: spring-test

I have a small Spring webapp.  Besides my plain unit tests, I'm writing a unit test that just verifies required bean wiring.  I'm using the default applicationContext.xml file, not a "test" version.  I do have some fake test resources that normally defined in my Tomcat JNDI context.

The test basically works, but one annoyance is that some scheduled tasks that are defined in the default context start up and emit some error messages that don't effect the test result.

The scheduled tasks are defined in the context like this:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="ratesQueryProcessor" method="run" fixed-rate="30000"/> <!--  Every 120 seconds -->
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Is there something that I can do in the spring context resulting from the default applicationContext.xml and my "test resources" XML file, and perhaps a JavaConfig class, which would "override" these scheduled tasks to turn them off?

If it matters, here's a small excerpt from my unit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "/testResources.xml"})
//@ContextHierarchy({
//    @ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"),
//    @ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringWiringTest.Config.class)
//})
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "env = tomcat", "doNotifications = false" })
public class SpringWiringTest {
```

The commented out section is because I'm attempting to define my test resources in a JavaConfig class, but at this point I'm unable to use BOTH an XML file and a JavaConfig class (I have another SO posting asking about this).

Answer (score 0):

This is a *duplicate* of [Disable a Spring Scheduler Task via Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017215/disable-a-spring-scheduler-task-via-property).

The solution is to use *bean definition profiles* (a.k.a., environment profiles).